# Debugging iptables using live packet views

Tags: linux, iptables, gui

Are there any CLI or GUI functions that I can use to monitor hits to `iptables` and watch as packets interact with `iptables`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to have this enabling modules ipt_LOG ipt6_LOG and using TRACE chain in raw table to debug streams/rules you need.

See http://backreference.org/2010/06/11/iptables-debugging/ for reference

Comment: Thats more like what I was after so see excactly which rules are being executed at which time.

Answer (score 25):

#### Visualizing the rules

*gressgraph*

You can use this tool, [gressgraph](http://freecode.com/projects/gressgraph), to create a visualization of the rules.

[image: ss of gressgraph]

*dot-iptables*

Another tool is called [`dot-iptables`](https://github.com/larsks/dot-iptables). It's a Python script that's similar to `gressgraph`.

*graph-itables*

A 3rd tool is called [`graph-iptables`](http://search.cpan.org/~mamawe/App-Iptables2Dot-v0.2.1/bin/iptables2dot). This tool is a Perl script which is again similar to the previous 2.

#### Visualizing the logs

There is also a tool called [Afterglow](http://afterglow.sourceforge.net/index.html) for visualizing the `iptables` log files. There's a nice tutorial available titled, [Use Afterglow To Visualize Iptables Logs On CentOS, RHEL, Fedora](http://lintut.com/use-afterglow-to-visualize-iptables-logs-on-centos-rhel-fedora/).

[image: ss of afterglow]

#### Realtime monitoring iptables

One method for doing this is to use a script, like this Perl script, to monitor `iptables` by running it every coule of seconds and collect the various counters on the different chains.

- [Real-time Iptables Monitor - perlmonks.org](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=513732)

Another method is to use a `top` like tool called [`iptstate`](http://www.phildev.net/iptstate/). You can also check out its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptstate) too.

[image: ss of iptstate]

You can see [more screenshots](http://www.phildev.net/iptstate/screenshot.shtml) here on the `iptstate` website.

Comment: excellent response, certainly opened my eyes up to some other possibilities.